# c# sort hand of playing cards

Tags: c#, sorting, playing-cards

I have a class Card with the following properties

```
public int value { get; private set; }
public string suit { get; private set; }
```

Once I have a player with a hand

```
List<Card> hand
```

How do I sort that hand, so that

1) primarily sorted into suits, with the largest (most cards) groups first, and smallest (least cards) groups last, and

2) withing those groups, sort them from high to low

Also, this is for Rook - almost identical to playing cards. values range from 1-14, with four suits - Red, Green, Yellow, and Black. In addition, there is one "Rook" card. Just a heads up in case this changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sorted = hand
    .GroupBy(l => l.Suit)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value));
```

Comment: Thank you! works 100% perfectly

Answer (score 4):

Linq is very useful for sorting:

```
var sorted = hand
    .GroupBy(x => x.suit)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Cards = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.value),
        Count = x.Count(),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Cards);
```

If you want to get fancier, you can make `suit` into it's own type with a `SortOrder`. This will let you have full control over things like cards with special suits.

```
class Suit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Or, as an enum:

```
enum Suit
{
    Hearts = 1, //1 = sort order
    Clubs = 2, 
    //...
    Rook = 5,
}
```

Comment: It should sort by the suits with the most number of cards desc.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make `Suit` an `enum`.

Comment: Almost worked! This was the output: crap... just a second for the edit, I pressed enter
5 of Black
6 of Black
8 of Green
9 of Green
6 of Red
7 of Red
8 of Red
13 of Red
0 of Rook
2 of Yellow
14 of Yellow

Comment: Suit should probably be an Enum, and you want to sort not by suit order but by count of cards of suit. Might be a job for GroupBy

Comment: @DaveZych i'm working on updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ap can you show me how the Enums would look?

Comment: @DLeh - `OrderByDescending` (for both sorts) :)

Comment: @DLeh How would I change my current properties in my Card class to accommodate for the suit class/enum

Comment: @DLeh nevermind haha, your answer below was a lot simpler and did EXACTLY what I wanted it to. Thanks a million :D

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 linked lists (one for each suit) and insert each card to the relevant place in the linked list (highest to lowest) and hold a counter for each list. based on the counter you will know how many card are for each suit and they will be sorted. just copy them to the finished array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hand.Sort((y, x) => (hand.Count(c => c.suit == x.suit).ToString("D2") + x.suit + "/" + x.value.ToString("D2"))
            .CompareTo(hand.Count(c => c.suit == y.suit).ToString("D2") + y.suit + "/" + y.value.ToString("D2")));
```